# Different way to export data from WP?

Tags: export, json

does anyone one if there is any other way how to export all data from WP than than the default  export plugin?

I need it because I have JSON arrays in my custom fields and when I import XML file which was done via default WP plugin for export so it's not the same JSON array (string). It seems that Wordpress when exports custom fields delete all "\" from JSON array so after export it's broken JSON array. So that's why I'm searching for any alternative how to export all WP data. Or if you know solution how to fix this problem it would be the best.

Thank you for all advices.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data?  You can just export the database itself using something like phpmyadmin if you're not comfortable in the command line.

Comment: So if I export database itself using phpmyadmin, will it export post attachments too?

Comment: attachments are a combination of a physical file and data in the database, you need both the database export and the physical files located in your uploads folder.